# Spring Controller always produce json

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is there anyway to force spring to always produce json, even an empty json object if there's no data to return.
Our services go through another service that rejects any response that isn't valid json (regardless of status code). It's not nice but we have no control of this.

With spring controllers you can tell them to produce json, but this only works when there's content to return. Is there a quick and elegant way to make all responses be json?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public
@ResponseBody
ResponseEntity<String> test(){
    // if this returns null or an empty string the response body will be emtpy 
    // and the content-type header will not be set.
    return service.getData();
}
```

The simply fix here is to simply add an if statement to check for null. But that's ugly as I'll have to manually set the header and the response body.

I'm hoping someone knows of a nicer way?

Thanks

Comment: How about throwing an exception in case the service is returning null/nothing and then use an ExceptionHandler to set appropriate response and header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all responses to return `application/json`, then you can set this at a single place by overriding `postHandle()` from `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`:

```
@Component
public class ResponseInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public void postHandle(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Object handler,
            final ModelAndView modelAndView) throws IOException {
         if (response.getContentType() == null || response.getContentType().equals("")) {
            response.setContentType("application/json");
         }
     }
}
```

You can look [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You may wrap the response in a "Container" object
For example I use this BaseAjaxResponse:

```
public class BaseAjaxResponse implements Serializable
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9087132709920851138L;
    private int codiceOperazione;
    private String descrizioneEsitoOperazione;
    private long numeroTotaleOggetti;
    private long numeroOggettiRestituiti;
    private List<? extends Object> payload;
    //Constructors and getter/setter

}
```

Then in my controllers I use this strategy:

```
@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.POST }, value = { "/find" })
    public ResponseEntity<BaseAjaxResponse> createCandidato(@RequestBody CandidatoDto candidato){
        BaseAjaxResponse bar = new BaseAjaxResponse();
        HttpStatus statusCode = null;
        List<Object> payload = null;
        StopWatch sw = new StopWatch("Find");
        try
        {
            sw.start();
            payload = myService.find();
            sw.stop();
            if( payload == null || payload.isEmpty() )
            {
                statusCode = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT;
                bar.setCodiceOperazione(statusCode.value());
                bar.setDescrizioneEsitoOperazione("No result"); 
            }
            else
            {
                statusCode = HttpStatus.OK;
                bar.setCodiceOperazione(statusCode.value());
                bar.setDescrizioneEsitoOperazione("Got result");    
                //Set the object count and the number of found objects
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            String message = "Errore nell'inserimento di un candidato; "+e.getMessage();
            statusCode = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
            bar.setCodiceOperazione(statusCode.value());
            bar.setDescrizioneEsitoOperazione(message);
            logger.error(message, e);

        }
        finally
        {
            if( sw.isRunning() )
            {
                sw.stop();
                if( logger.isDebugEnabled() )
                {
                    logger.debug("CHIUSURA STOPWATCH FORZATA. "+sw.toString());
                }
            }
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<BaseAjaxResponse>(bar, statusCode);
    }
```

I hope this can be useful

Angelo

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work as the service returns a string. I'm working with a lot of other services and I'm quite limited with any refactoring unfortunately.

Comment: What I really need is to have null or an empty string convert to an empty json object. The problem with the wrapper approach is that it is adding fields, whereas I need an empty json object.

Comment: Well you may use a custom message converter then; in this message converter you can handle the JSON as you want